# MVC RouteLink URL format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following `RouteLink`:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Accept Offer", new { controller = "Case", action = "Accept", id = item.CaseId, offerid = item.PxOfferId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

Which formats the URL as:

```
http://localhost:54644/Clients/Case/Accept/15847?offerid=3103
```

How do I format the URL to be:

```
http://localhost:54644/Clients/Case/Accept/15847/3103
```

Thanks.

Default route:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "Clients_default",
        "Clients/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Route works if I put this first in my defined routes:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        name: "Accept Offer",
        url: "Clients/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{offerid}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Case", action = "Accept", id = 0, offerid = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

but then causes errors on other pages.

Comment: You need to define a specific route with a placeholder for `offerid`

Comment: Try adding `offerId` on route configuration like this: `{controller}/{action}/{id}/{offerid}` and declare `offerid` as `UrlParameter.Optional`.

Comment: can you share the route definition you have in `RouteConfig` ? If you don't have one set up you'll need to do that. Then you will be able to achieve the url format your require

Comment: @scgough just added that info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nee a Route in the `RouteConfig` file in `App_Start` (if you are using mvc3/4 then routes *might* be configured in the `Global.asax` file instead):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyCaseRoute",
    url: "/clients/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{offerId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Case", action = "Accept", id = UrlParameter.Optional, offerId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

usage:

```
@Html.RouteLink("My Link Text", routeName: "MyCaseRoute", routeValues: new { controller = "case", action = "accept", id = 1, offerId = 2 })
```

Comment: Only the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional` and you should also note that this should be before any other matching routes

Comment: I'm using MVC 5. The route displays correctly if I put the above route first, but then this causes errors on every other page.

Comment: This is the route I put it above:

            `context.MapRoute(
                "Clients_default",
                "Clients/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: Ah, got it working. Thanks for the info, the error I was getting was because it was becuase of the default controller and action I had on the mapped route as the Accept action requires offerid parameter. your info helped me though.